# how do I get the value from the drop down list to transfer to cart page

Tags: javascript, dynamic, drop-down-menu, store

I'm trying to retrieve a value from my dropdown list that is created dynamically from MYSQL using javascript. I'm fairly new to javascript as well, and was wondering if I have this done correctly.

```
function addtocart(prod_id, color_ID)
{
document.productform.productid.value = prod_id;
var idx = getField("dropdown").selectedIndex;
var color_ID = getField("dropdown").options[idx].value; 
document.productform.command.value = 'add';
document.productform.submit();
}
</script>
```

I was trying to use this, but it is only passing the last option value of every drop down.

```
function addtocart(prod_id, color_ID)
{
document.productform.productid.value = prod_id;
document.productform.Color.value = color_ID;
document.productform.command.value = 'add';
document.productform.submit();
}
```

This is where I'm trying to pull it from:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM color c JOIN inventory i ON ( c.Color_ID = i.Color_ID ) JOIN product p ON ( p.Prod_ID = i.Prod_ID ) WHERE p.Prod_ID = $p_ID";  
    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1) or die("Error querying database");

    Print "<p>Decorative Color:\n";
    Print "<select name=\"dropdown\">";

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    $color_ID = $row['Color_ID'];

    Print "<option value=".$row['Color_ID']."> " . $row['Color'] . "\n     </option>";

    }

    Print "</select>\n";
    Print "</p>\n";
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're having, or what problem you're trying to solve. If you have a form with a select box it'll be submitted along with the rest of the form.

Comment: Please put in all the code. From the code snippets you provided, it's impossible to tell where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit this form and your only problem is how to make your dropdown list to show the color value that is saved in the database, then you probably need something like:

```
document.productform.dropdown.value = color_ID;
```

This must be called during onLoad in the body of your html

Or with php inside your while loop with an if statement inside the `<option>` tag like:

```
{if $row['Color_ID'] == $color_ID} selected {/if}
```